# Equivalent Functions for JSON/B Operators in Postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql

I've tried to dig through the documentation and can't seem to find anything for what I'm looking for. Are there equivalent functions for the various JSON/B operators (`->`, `->>`, `@>`, `?`, etc) in PostgreSQL?

Edit: To clarify, I would like to know if it is possible to have the following grouped queries return the same result:

```sql
SELECT '{"foo": "bar"}'::json->>'foo';                   -- 'bar'
SELECT json_get_value('{"foo": "bar"}'::json, 'foo');    -- 'bar'

SELECT '{"foo": "bar"}'::jsonb ? 'foo';                  -- t
SELECT jsonb_key_exists('{"foo": "bar"}'::jsonb, 'foo'); -- t
```

Comment: just curious, which thing are you comparing to which has those operators

Comment: @AnthonySottile I guess an example could be `ST_GeomFromText(geom)` and `geom::geometry`. I know they're not directly equal, but similar idea

Comment: What actually are you trying to do? And operators based in what language? JSON itself does not have such operators.

Comment: @JorgeCampos They're available in [Postgresql](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html), I'll update my question with an example

Comment: I know that. Then the question is, equivalent in what? JSON itself?

Comment: Which Postgres version are you using? Postgres 12 has `jsonb_path_exists` which could be used as a replacement for the `?` operator

Comment: So your question is **Postgresql JSON/B Operators** Compared to **Postgresql JSON functions** you should make that clear in your question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the system catalogs to discover the function equivalent to each operator.

```
select * from pg_catalog.pg_operator where oprname ='?';
```

This shows that the function is named "jsonb_exists".  Some operators are overloaded and will give more than one function, you have to look at the argument types to distinguish them.

Every operator has a function 'behind' it.  That function may or may not be documented in its own right.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there are two functions which are equivalents to `#>` and `#>>` operators.

These are:

- `#>` `json_extract_path`
- `#>>` `json_extract_path_text`
- `->>` `json_extract_path_text` -- credits: @a_horse_with_no_name

[Discover more in the docs](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html)

Other than that you could extract json to a table and take values you need using regular SQL query vs a table using `json_each` or `json_each_text`.

Same thing with checking if a key exists in a JSON would be to use `json_object_keys` and also query the table which comes out of it.

If you need to wrap things up in a different language / using ORM then what you could do is move the data retrieval logic to a PL/SQL procedure and just execute it and obtain prepared data from it.

Obviously, you could also build your own functions that would implement the behaviour of forementioned operators, but the question is: is it really worth it? It will definitely be slower.

Comment: "is it really worth it" it is not if I have to build them myself, I was hoping I could use an existing ORM without any hacky workarounds. Thank you!

Comment: Exactly. I meant to eventually wrap the operators behaviour in a function which adds a bit of overhead but would still work. You would have to implement couple of functions for each operator and then execute these. Their body would still be using JSON operator to check for existence or retrieve the value you need and this way you could work with these functions in ORM.

Comment: From my experience, for some more work than just simply checking if the attribute exists, we wrapped the logic inside a PL/pgSQL procedure and did everything JSON-wise on the database side to return it back to the application.

Comment: @GammaGames: you can also use `json_extract_path_text` as a replacement for  `->>`

Comment: Included this usage with credits to @a_horse_with_no_name. Thanks :-)